# Specific url and parameter in Node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have 2 qeustions : 
1. I want my project's url to be like 127.0.0.1:8080/param=id  and I couldnt do it, I tried:

```
app.get('/param=id', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.param("id"));
});
```

if I write `'/param/:id'` it works but I dont want the url to look like this

I want my program to send message according to the id a json message or string to the client

So my second question is how the client gets the response - I want the message to go throgh a script in the client's side?

Comment: Why don't you want to use query?

Comment: what do you mean?
like '/param/:id' ? 
because I have an exrecise and thats how it should be done

Comment: `/param=id` is a very odd URL. It looks like munging together path and query. Wouldn't it more likely be `/param/:param` or `/?param=id`?

Comment: I tried it right now writing this, but it didnt print the parameter

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query) instead of [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.query.id);
  // or you may still use req.param("id")
});
```

requesting it like

```
HTTP GET 127.0.0.1:8080/?id=my_id
```

`query` is a different way of sending data to the server, designed to send key-value pairs.

Though, if `id` is the only thing you want to send to the server, I would recommend to stick with `params`, e.g.:

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.id);
});
```

requesting it like

```
HTTP GET 127.0.0.1:8080/my_id
```

Comment: its now working for me . error :500 TypeError: Property 'query' of object #<IncomingMessage> is not a function

Comment: please explain **why** would `req.query` would work instead of `req.params`

Comment: It's not like `req.query` would work and `req.params` would not. Query is a different way of sending data to the server, designed to send key-value pairs.

Comment: This is the cleaner way of building an Interface ;) +1